# How to correctly link a c++/CLR wrapper to an unmanged c++ dll and use it in a c# program

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, clr

I'm trying to link to a dll compiled as unmanaged c++ code from another c++ dll that wraps the useful unmanaged code and is compiled with CLR. I then want to use that wrapper in a c# app. 
However all attempts so far have failed for various reasons.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for this project.

I start by creating a c# project. `File->new->project->visual c#->console app (.NET Framework)`

I then create my c++/clr project by right clicking the solution and doing: `add->new project->visual c++->clr->clr empty project`.
I need my c++/clr project to be a dll so I go to `properties->Configuration Properties->General->Configuration Type` and set the value to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`

Now, I need my C# project to reference this one so I right click on my c# project and go to `add->reference` then I select my c++/clr project
(I know that everything is correct up to this point because I can call my c++/clr functions from the c# project and get the desired output. The issue comes when I continue to try and call unmanaged code.).

Now that I have that set up, I can create my unmanaged c++ project so I follow similar steps but this time I create a C++ Empty Project and again change the configuration properties to be a DLL. I then add the unmanaged c++ project as a reference to the c++/clr project by right clicking the c++/clr project and going `add->reference`

Now I have my 3 projects and the references that I need, I can then start adding my code so I add two files to each c++ project:

I don't think the code itself is particularly interesting to this question but I include it anyway so that anyone can quickly reproduce the problem. In the unmanaged c++ project, I have a header containing:

```
// UnmanagedHeader.h
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) void HelloDLL();
```

and in the source file:

```
#include "UnmanagedHeader.h"
#include <iostream>

void HelloDLL() { std::cout << "Hello from unmanaged dll!" << std::endl; }
```

Then in the c++/clr project I have a header containing:

```
// Header.h
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Project1
{
    public ref class Class1
    {
    public:
                // contruct this class
        Class1();
                // Call a function from the unmanaged project
        void UnmanagedWrap();
    };
}
```

and a source file containing:

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "../Project2/UnmanagedHeader.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace Project1
{
    Class1::Class1() { std::cout << "Hello From Class1" << std::endl; }
    void Class1::UnmanagedWrap() { HelloDLL(); }
}
```

and finally, in my c# project I have one file containing:

```
using System;
using Project1;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.UnmanagedWrap();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This all compiles just fine but when I go to run the application, I get a runtime error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Project1.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

Project1.dll is the c++/clr project but I expect the issue is related to my unmanaged c++ dll not being set up correctly. I know that Project1.dll (c++/clr) exists and so does Project2.dll (unmanaged c++).

Could anyone explain to me what I need to do for my unmanaged c++ dll to be compatible with the c++/clr and c# projects?

Update: Something I just tried that may be of help, If I try to add a reference from the c++/clr project to the unmanaged dll drectly (not selecting the project but instead brwsing for the built dll and selecting that) I get: `Could not add a reference to "<path>/Project2.dll" as it is not of a type or version this project can use.`

Comment: 1. Ensure that the project1.dll is in the same folder as the managed clr dll.
2. Check that all dependencies of the project1.dll are in the directory. Use a tool like 
"dependency walker" for that. http://www.dependencywalker.com
3. Have you dependencies in you c++ project? Visual studio debug binaries? missing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ManuelAmstutz . The dlls are both in the same directory and there shouldn't be any other dependencies since the only thing tha gets used is `iosteam` and the compiler definitely knows about that

Comment: It is an entirely normal mishap.  When you build the EXE project then the build system can discover its dependencies from the assembly metadata and knows to copy them.  But it can't do that for the native DLL, it doesn't appear in metadata.  So it stays behind in the wrong spot, the solution's Debug directory, and the OS doesn't know how to find it there.  You have to help get it copied, XCOPY /d in a post build event gets it done.  Or by changing the C++ project's General > Output Directory setting, crude but effective.

Comment: @HansPassant That was exactly it! thank you very muh